Should I still report cash earning on a 1040NR
I'm working illegally and undocumented in the US, can I still report cash earning on a 1040NR

If you're a US tax resident then you should use the form 1040.
In order to use 1040NR you need to either be a foreigner outside the US or only stay in the US for short periods, or have your presence days in the US excluded due to a legal status that qualifies. Since you do not have a legal status at all, you cannot exclude your presence days. Thus, if you pass the substantial presence test you're a US resident for tax purposes.
Similarly, you'll need to pay and file returns for State taxes in the state where you live.
Being a resident for tax purposes has no bearing on your immigration status, and doesn't mean you're allowed to legally work. But, income earned illegally is still income and is taxed and you must report it.
If you don't have an SSN (yours, real one), you'll need to apply for ITIN to report your income.
When/if you get to sorting out your immigration status, you might be required to prove that you have in fact paid all your taxes during the years of illegal/undocumented presence.
